# Can I excplicitly call a function in an imported module like myModule.MyFunction() in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, module

If I have imported moduleFoo to my script in which there is a function Bar().

Can I call this function somehow like:

```
moduleFoo.Bar
```

instead of

```
Bar
```

So that the person reading the script can understand from which module this Bar is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give to your function name like:

```
moduleFoo.Bar # prefixing each function in your module with the module name + .
```

but this is not respecting the standard powershell naming convention for function or cmdlet (verb-noum).

You can also create alias that prefix the function/cmdlet with `modulefoo.`

If you only need to know the name of the module to which  the function/cmdlet belongs you can use:

```
(gcm bar).Modulename
```

Comment: This doesnt seems to work for me, any explaination ?
`PS>(gcm df).ModuleName  
CoreSmac  

PS>CoreSmac.df  
CoreSmac.df : Le terme «CoreSmac.df» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de
commande, fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez
l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le chemin
d'accès est correct et réessayez.
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ CoreSmac.df
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CoreSmac.df:String) [], CommandNotFo
   undException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: @Kayasax there is a misunderstanding: `(gcm bar).Modulename` return the name of the module where the cmdlet/function came from.

Comment: yes I understood, running (gcm df).ModuleName  -> PS respond CoreSmac. Now I call CoreSmac.df -> CommandNotFound ... @Christian

Comment: @Kayasax Sorry.. but I didn't say in my answer that after `(gcm df).ModuleName` you can call the `df` cmdlet as `CoreSmac.df`. Here is the misunderstanding ;)

Comment: Woaw, in you response you told #prefix each function in your module with the module name + .  CoreSmac is my module name , df is my function name So CoreSmac.df should work no ?  
BTW, I cannot start my comment with @Christian do you know why ?

Comment: @Kayasax maybe for this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98923. I've edit my answer, try re-read maybe now is more understandable.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that is effectively more understandable ;) thank you and thanks again for the link . Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could call it like $moduleFoo.Bar if you import the module with the -AsCustomObject switch :

```
$moduleFoo = Import-Module moduleFoo -AsCustomObject
$moduleFoo.Bar
```

Another option would be to just call it using the command full name (module\command):

```
PS> moduleFoo\Bar
```